# Three.js LineBasicMaterial linewidth issue

Tags: three.js, webgl

When I working with CanvasRendereer then linewidth of LineBasicMaterial working fine but when I switch to WebGL then its not working only default linewidth is applied in material. I found some post regarding this issue and I got idea that its not working in windows for ANGLE issue.

Is this problem still there?

If this problem is solved then how to use it or if not solved then is there any other way to implement linewidth in WebGL?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is there, and IIRC it is very unlikely to change. The standard workaround is to use rectangles that look like wide lines.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain the second line?

Comment: See http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/ and http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632159/three-js-wireframe-model-from-vtk-file.

Comment: @WestLangley My requirement is to increase the thickness of line. My requirement is not solved by using WireFrame. Even I also tried with WireFrameHelper but still I have the same problem.

Comment: The issue is still there because direct3D does not support lineWidth

Comment: @gaitat Is there any other way to set the linewidth or similar to linewidth?

Comment: It should be supported if you go to native gl. http://www.geeks3d.com/20130611/webgl-how-to-enable-native-opengl-in-your-browser-windows/

Comment: @gaitat Yes. You are right.  When I working with CanvasRenderer then linewidth function working fine but when I switched to WebGL then  its not working. I need to working in WebGL.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=334 and https://cesiumjs.org/2013/04/22/Robust-Polyline-Rendering-with-WebGL/

Comment: @WestLangley I am really not able to implement custom shader to display  a line with thickness. Can you please provide a simple example so that I can understand how to do that?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread your question. You want to draw a thick line, not a thick wireframe mesh.... I have not tried to do that, but here is a link: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/05/webgl-rendering-of-solid-trails/.

Comment: Look at http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2014/09/08/rendering-lines-and-bezier-curves-in-three-js-and-webgl/. That article links to this example: http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/vector/tests/test_lines4.html.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help. Used some technique like adding offset for start and end point to draw a thick line.

Answer (score 1):

WebGL does not support line width for three js

See https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/TubeGeometry

> WebGL renderer on Windows platforms linewidth will always be 1
>   regardless of the set value.

You could use TubeGeometry

https://github.com/jjcc1421/Three3DExtras

```
var line=new three3DExtras.tubeLine([-1,-1,0],[1,1,0],0.02,'#FFF');
var line2=new three3DExtras.tubeLine([-1,0,0],[1,0,0],0.02,'#E3DC1C');
var line3=new three3DExtras.tubeLine([-1,0,1],[1,0,1],0.02,'#B02735');
scene.add(line.getObject3D());
scene.add(line2.getObject3D());
scene.add(line3.getObject3D());
```